# I am using ubuntu OS now and try to run code of nodejs. I am getting syntax error though the same code when run on Windows 10 every thing was fine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

VS code version: 1.61.1

version of nodejs: v10.19.0

Actual code is :

```
    import express from 'express';
    import fetch from 'node-fetch';
    const app= express();
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.get('/project', async(req, res)=>{
    const api_url='https://stage.hypermine.in/whitelist/api/v1/project/test----give-away?isPublic=true';
    const fetch_response= await fetch(app_url);
    const result= await fetch_response.json();
         res.json(result);
 });

   app.listen(3000, ()=>{
         console.log('start listening');
 });
```

error I  encountered:-

```sh
varsha@varsha-Vostro-15-3568:~/Documents/demo_tests$ node demo

/home/varsha/Documents/demo_tests/demo.js:3
import express from 'express';
       ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Comment: Node v10 is very old. You need to install a recent version of node.

Comment: Try `import * as express from "express";`

Comment: You need node 12 and up to use imports statements.